# Allow multiple user accounts to be created having the same email address - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Does anyone know how disable the function in Woocommerce that disallows users to share the same email address when checking out.

I have managed to allow a user to share the same email address in Wordpress, but when the user checks out using Woocommerce it says email address already in use.

I would like to disable that function in Woocommerce, so that users can share the same email address.

Comment: A hacky way for users would be using me+something@email.com. I guess, these would be seen as unique by WC.

Answer (score 0):

This might help http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/9960 I understand it may be what you are looking for in terms of altering the core way WC handles duplicate emails/accounts.